# PANDAS Python | Contain specific value in specific position

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, contains

I'm trying to select just the rows that on the column "Cuenta" contain "05" in the third and fourth position , for example : 51**05**0300 , 51**05**0600

| Año | Periodo | Cuenta |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023 | 1 | 51050300 |
| 2023 | 2 | 51053900 |
| 2023 | 1 | 74359570 |
| 2023 | 2 | 74452500 |
| 2023 | 6 | 51050300 |
| 2023 | 7 | 51050600 |
| 2023 | 7 | 52351005 |
| 2023 | 7 | 52353505 |
| 2023 | 7 | 52159500 |

I'm using this code:

```
pattern=r'..05*' 

df[df['Cuenta'].str.contains(pattern)]
```

But it doesn´t work, How can I do it?

Comment: Do you have an error or an empty result?

Comment: with this code, the result is the same dataframe, it didn´t apply the condition that I need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change your pattern:

```
pattern = '^..05'  # ^ means from the begin string

>>> df['Cuenta'].astype(str).str.contains(pattern)
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
4     True
5     True
6    False
7    False
8    False
Name: Cuenta, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 3):

For fun, assuming an integer column, an arithmetic solution would be:

```
m = df['Cuenta'].floordiv(10**(np.ceil(np.log10(df['Cuenta'])-1)-3)).mod(100).eq(5)
out = df.loc[m]
```

Or, if the number of digits is fixed:

```
m = df['Cuenta']//10000%100 == 5
```

How it works:

```
df.assign(n_digits=np.ceil(np.log10(df['Cuenta'])-1)+1,
          first_4=lambda d: d['Cuenta'].floordiv(10**(d['n_digits']-4)),
          digits_3_4=lambda d: d['first_4'].mod(100)
         )

    Año  Periodo    Cuenta  n_digits  first_4  digits_3_4
0  2023        1  51050300       8.0   5105.0         5.0
1  2023        2  51053900       8.0   5105.0         5.0
2  2023        1  74359570       8.0   7435.0        35.0
3  2023        2  74452500       8.0   7445.0        45.0
4  2023        6  51050300       8.0   5105.0         5.0
5  2023        7  51050600       8.0   5105.0         5.0
6  2023        7  52351005       8.0   5235.0        35.0
7  2023        7  52353505       8.0   5235.0        35.0
8  2023        7  52159500       8.0   5215.0        15.0
9  2024        8     12051       5.0   1205.0         5.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Or like this:

```
df[df['Cuenta'].astype(str).str[2:4] == '05']
```

Output:

```
    Año  Periodo    Cuenta
0  2023        1  51050300
1  2023        2  51053900
4  2023        6  51050300
5  2023        7  51050600
```